# Why decltype works here but not auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the code as below:

```
template <typename T, typename sepT = char>
void print2d(const T &data, sepT sep = ',') {
    for(auto i = std::begin(data); i < std::end(data); ++i) {
        decltype(*i) tmp = *i;
        for(auto j = std::begin(tmp); j < std::end(tmp); ++j) {
            std::cout << *j << sep;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v = {{11}, {2,3}, {33,44,55}};
    print2d(v);

    int arr[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    print2d(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the `decltype` to `auto`, it won't compile and complain (partial error):

```
2d_iterator.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void print2d(const T&, sepT) [with T = int [2][2]; sepT = char]’:
2d_iterator.cpp:21:21:   required from here
2d_iterator.cpp:9:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const int*&)’
2d_iterator.cpp:9:36: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iterator:64,
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `decltype` yields `int(&)[2]`, whilst plain `auto` forces a pointer conversion (same rules as template argument deduction). Just use `auto&`.

Comment: @Xeo That should be an answer.

Comment: @Xeo Can you make an answer? Also can you point me a URL that explain this deduction rule?

Comment: @texasbruce The rules are defined in **§7.1.6.4 auto specifier** paragraph 6 and 7. You may find this useful: Scott Meyers' blog: [Universal References in C++11—Scott Meyers](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: please use `i != std::end(data)` instead of `<`: the latter assumes random access iterators, so passing a `std::list` to your `print2d` will fail.

Comment: @couchdeveloper I do not see anywhere it says auto forces pointer conversion?

Comment: @texasbruce "... the type of the declared variable using the declarator-id is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for **template argument deduction**"  - and in the meantime kindly explained by Marc Garcia. :)

Comment: @couchdeveloper and where in standard says template argument deduction of array converts to pointer?

Comment: @texasbruce 14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call, under 2 "If P is not a reference type": "If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of A for type deduction;" (where A represents the argument, and P the parameter of that function call)

Comment: @texasbruce and: "4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array]
1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array."

Comment: Have you tried a recent compiler?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer summed-up in one comment:

> `decltype` yields `int(&)[2]`, whilst plain `auto` forces a pointer conversion (same rules as template argument deduction). Just use `auto&`. - [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824013/why-decltype-works-here-but-not-auto#comment33029797_21824013)

---

@Xeo's comment-answer basically says that because `auto` involves the same rules as [template argument type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Template_argument_deduction), `auto` deduces a pointer (`int*`) type out of the source's array type (of `i`, specifically `int(&)[2]`).

There is something great in your code: it actually demonstrates how template type deduction behaves when the parameter is a reference and how the reference affects how the type is being deduced.

```
template <typename T, typename sepT = char>
void print2d(const T &data, sepT sep = ',') {
    ...
}

...

int arr[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
print2d(arr);
```

You can see that `data` is of type `const T&`, a reference to a `const T`. Now, it is being passed with `arr`, whose type is `int[2][2]`, which is an array of two arrays of two `int`s (whoo!). Now come template argument type deduction. On this situation, it rules that with `data` being a **reference**, `T` should be deduced with the original type of the argument, which is `int[2][2]`. Then, it applies any qualifications to the parameter type to the *parameter*, and with `data`'s qualified type being `const T&`, the `const` and `&` qualifiers are applied and so `data`'s type is `const int (&) [2][2]`.

```
template <typename T, typename sepT = char>
void print2d(const T &data, sepT sep = ',') {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int[2][2]>::value, "Fail");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(data), const int(&)[2][2]>::value, "Fail");
}

...

int arr[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
print2d(arr);
```

[**LIVE CODE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8184a0b4df3698b)

However, **if** `data` would have been a **non-reference**, template argument type deduction rules that if the argument's type is an array type (e.g. `int[2][2]`), [the array type shall "decay" to its corresponding pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7797839/1619294), thus making `int[2][2]` into `int(*)[2]` (plus `const` if parameter is `const`) ([fix courtesy of @Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824013/why-decltype-works-here-but-not-auto#comment33033712_21825321)).

---

Great! I just explained the part that is entirely not what caused the error. (And I just explained a great deal of template magic)...

... Nevermind about that. Now to the error. But before we go, keep this on your mind:

```
auto == template argument type deduction
         + std::initializer_list deduction for brace init-lists   // <-- This std::initializer_list thingy is not relevant to your problem,
                                                                  //    and is only included to prevent any outbreak of pedantry.
```

Now, your code:

```
for(auto i = std::begin(data); i < std::end(data); ++i) {
    decltype(*i) tmp = *i;
    for(auto j = std::begin(tmp); j < std::end(tmp); ++j) {
        std::cout << *j << sep;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Some prerequisites before the battle:

- `decltype(data) == const int (&) [2][2]`
- `decltype(i) == const int (*) [2]` (see [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)), which is a pointer to an `int[2]`.

Now when you do `decltype(*i) tmp = *i;`, `decltype(*i)` would return `const int(&)[2]` , a reference to an `int[2]` (remember the word dereference). Thus, it is also `tmp`'s type. **You preserved the original type by using `decltype(*i)`**.

However, when you do

```
auto tmp = *i;
```

Guess what `decltype(tmp)` is: `int*`! Why? Because all of the blabbery-blablablah above, and some template magic.

So, why the error with `int*`? Because **`std::begin` expects an array type**, not its lesser decayed-to pointer. Thus, `auto j = std::begin(tmp)` would cause an error when `tmp` is `int*`.

How to solve (also **tl;dr**)?

- Keep as-is. Use `decltype`.
- Guess what. Make your `auto`ed variable a reference!

  ```
  auto& tmp = *i;
  ```

  [**LIVE CODE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26193401bc212ab5)

  or

  ```
  const auto& tmp = *i;
  ```

  if you don't intend to modify the contents of `tmp`. ([Greatness by Jon Purdy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824013/why-decltype-works-here-but-not-auto/21825321#comment33032316_21825321))

---

<sub><sub>Moral of the story: A great comment saves a man a thousand words.</sub></sub>

---

**UPDATE:** added `const` to the types given by `decltype(i)` and `decltype(*i)`, as `std::begin(data)` would return a `const` pointer due to `data` also being `const` ([fix by litb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824013/why-decltype-works-here-but-not-auto/21825321?noredirect=1#comment33084351_21825321), thanks)

Comment: `const auto&` would be even better.

Comment: still, can you point me where in C++11 spec that says auto forces a pointer conversion?

Comment: @JonPurdy `auto&` is enough, for it also deduces `const` if the source is also `const`, but yeah, that is much better if you don't intend to modify your variable.

Comment: I wrote this function myself so I dont really need explanation on how it works. The only explanation I need is what you described as `some template magic`. Xeo has been clear enough on why, and all I need other than that is an official reference.

Comment: @texasbruce Sorry, I misread your comment. The part of the standard can be seen on `14.8.2 Template argument deduction`, specifically 14.8.2.1 onwards.

Comment: In C++1y i believe ‘decltype(auto)‘ will do the right thing too. Not experimented yet though.

Comment: Nice answer. But why is `decltype(i)` not `const int (*) [2]` instead of `int (*) [2]`? After all, `data` was deduced as `const int (&) [2][2]` so `std::begin` should better return something pointing to const data?