# What is std::decay and when it should be used?

Tags: c++, c++11, standard-library

What are the reasons for the existence of [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)?
In what situations is [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) useful?

Comment: It is used in the standard library e.g. when passing arguments to a thread. Those need to be *stored*, by value, so you cannot store e.g. arrays. Instead, a pointer is stored and so on. It is also a metafunction that mimics the function parameter type adjustments.

Comment: `decay_t<decltype(...)>` is a nice combination, to see what `auto` would deduce.

Comment: [meta.trans.other] states: This
behavior is similar to the [... = several] conversions
applied when an lvalue expression is
used as an rvalue, but also strips
cv-qualifiers from class types **in order
to more closely model by-value
argument passing**."

Comment: std::decay() can do three things. 1 It is able to convert an array of T to T*; 2. It can remove cv qualifier and reference; 3. It converts function T to T*. e.g decay(void(char)) -> void(*)(char). Seems no one mentioned the third usage in the answers.

Comment: @r0ng It actually does *none* of these things, since it isn’t a function.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

<sub><joke>It's obviously used to decay radioactive `std::atomic` types into non-radioactive ones.</joke></sub>

[N2609](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2069.html) is the paper that proposed `std::decay`. The paper explains:

> Simply put, `decay<T>::type` is the identity type-transformation except
>   if T is an array type or a reference to a function type. In those
>   cases the `decay<T>::type` yields a pointer or a pointer to a function,
>   respectively.

The motivating example is C++03 `std::make_pair`:

```
template <class T1, class T2> 
inline pair<T1,T2> make_pair(T1 x, T2 y)
{ 
    return pair<T1,T2>(x, y); 
}
```

which accepted its parameters by value to make string literals work:

```
std::pair<std::string, int> p = make_pair("foo", 0);
```

If it accepted its parameters by reference, then `T1` will be deduced as an array type, and then constructing a `pair<T1, T2>` will be ill-formed.

But obviously this leads to significant inefficiencies. Hence the need for `decay`, to apply the set of transformations that occurs when pass-by-value occurs, allowing you to get the efficiency of taking the parameters by reference, but still get the type transformations needed for your code to work with string literals, array types, function types and the like:

```
template <class T1, class T2> 
inline pair< typename decay<T1>::type, typename decay<T2>::type > 
make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y)
{ 
    return pair< typename decay<T1>::type, 
                 typename decay<T2>::type >(std::forward<T1>(x), 
                                            std::forward<T2>(y)); 
}
```

**Note:** this is not the actual C++11 `make_pair` implementation - the C++11 `make_pair` also unwraps `std::reference_wrapper`s.

Comment: "T1 will be deduced as an array type, and then constructing a pair<T1, T2> will be ill-formed." what is the problem here?

Comment: I get it, in this way we will get  pair<char[4],int>  which can only accept strings with 4 characters

Comment: @camino I don't get it, are you saying that without std::decay the the first part of the pair would occupy 4 bytes for four chars instead of a one pointer to char? Is that what the std::forward does? Stops it from decaying from an array to a pointer?

Comment: @Zebrafish It is array decay. For example: template<typename T>
void f(T&);  f("abc"); T is char(&)[4],   but template<typename T>
void f(T);  f("abc"); T is char*;   You can also find an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797839/why-does-the-array-decay-to-a-pointer-in-a-template-function

Comment: Late to the party, but can you confirm that the pair<char[4], int> instantiation will still "work" as it is convertible into pair<string, int>, but the issue here is that this will generate too many function template instantiations? one for pair<char[0], int>, pair<char[1], int>, ....

Comment: @AdrianMuljadi No, you can't copy arrays.

Comment: @camino Quoting the paper: "the above code would fail to compile because we suddenly create a temporary pair object of the type `std::pair<const char[4],int>` (**and this instantiation fails because arrays are not constructible with the T() syntax, nor are they copy-constructible**)"

Comment: @camino So maybe guaranteed copy elision solves the problem as well, at least in this case, but of course it wasn't available yet.

Answer (score 114):

When dealing with template functions that take parameters of a template type, you often have universal parameters.  Universal parameters are almost always references of one sort or another.  They're also const-volatile qualified.  As such, most type traits don't work on them as you'd expect:

```
template<class T>
void func(T&& param) {
    if (std::is_same<T,int>::value) 
        std::cout << "param is an int\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "param is not an int\n";
}

int main() {
    int three = 3;
    func(three);  //prints "param is not an int"!!!!
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24476e60bd906bed

The solution here is to use `std::decay`:

```
template<class T>
void func(T&& param) {
    if (std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type,int>::value) 
        std::cout << "param is an int\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "param is not an int\n";
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cbd0119a28a18bd

Comment: I'm not happy with this. `decay` is very aggressive, e.g. if applied to a reference to array it yields a pointer. It is typically too aggressive for this kind of metaprogramming IMHO.

Comment: @dyp, what's less "aggressive" then? What are alternatives?

Comment: @SergeRogatch In the case of "universal parameters" / universal references / forwarding references, I'd just `remove_const_t< remove_reference_t<T> >`, possibly wrapped in a custom metafunction.

Comment: where is param even being used? It's an argument of func but I don't see it being used anywhere

Comment: @savram: In these pieces of code: it isn't. We're only checking the type, not the value. Everything should work fine if not better if we removed the name of the parameter.

Comment: @MooingDuck *Universal parameters are almost always references of one sort or another.* --> Is there any case in which universal reference aren't references?

Comment: @ElProfesor: Interesting question. I suppose there's some cases where it might deduce as `func<int>`, maybe when given the return value of a function that returns an `int`?  Specifying it explicitly will make it definitely not a reference.

Comment: @MooingDuck a call to a function that returns `int` (i.e., a function that returns an `int` *by value*) is a *prvalue*. `T` will be deduced to `int` and `param` will result in `int&&` (it does make sense so that it can be moved). So, `param` is still a reference for that case. If you can think of any case where `param` won't be a reference, let me know please.

Comment: @ElProfesor: I think all that leaves is when the caller specifies it explicitly.  `func<int>(3)`

Comment: @MooingDuck I think calling `func<int>(3)` will instantiate the template function `func` as `void func(int&& param)`. So, `param` would still be a reference. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ElProfesor: `param` is a universal reference, not an rreference, so reference folding kicks in. I believe `func<int>(3)` instantiates `void func(int param)`, but [my tests have sketchy conclusions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45fd4abb8c3cd35b)

Comment: @MooingDuck You are looking at `T`, but `param`'s type is the one resulting from `T&&` after reference collapsing is applied. According to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4c7f2c32a54fad0), `func<int>(3)` seems to be `void func(int&& param)` (look at the type of `f`).

Comment: Why does the first one not work? Because `param` is an r-value `int&&`? And an r-value int apparently isn't an int, right?

Comment: @GabrielStaples yes. According to template, `int`, `const int`, `int&`, `const int&`, `int&&`, `const int&&`, `volatile int`, `volatile int&`, `volatile int&&`, etc are all different.