# Why doesn't forwarding reference work in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, forwarding-reference

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename = decltype(&T::size)>
void f1(T)
{}

template<typename T, typename = decltype(&T::size)>
void f2(T&)
{}

template<typename T, typename = decltype(&T::size)>
void f3(T&&)
{}

int main()
{
    vector<int> coll;

    f1(coll); // ok
    f2(coll); // ok
    f3(coll); // error : no matching function for call to 'f3'
}
```

> main.cpp(21,6):  note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with `T` = > 
>   `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > &`]: type
>   '`std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > &`' cannot be used prior to
>   '`::`' because it has no members
>
> `void f3(T&&)`

My compiler is clang 4.0.

To my surprise, `f3(coll)` fails, while `f1(coll)` and `f2(coll)` are both ok.

**Why does a forwarding reference not work in this case?**

Comment: Show us the note about the error as well.

Comment: @user2079303, see my update.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: T.C.: the brackets.

Comment: It pays to read error messages closely. The `&` present in the substitution might have tipped you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because `T` is deduced as a reference type, you need to use [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::size)>
void f3(T&&)
{}
```

Full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename = decltype(&T::size)>
void f1(T)
{}

template<typename T, typename = decltype(&T::size)>
void f2(T&)
{}

template<typename T, typename = decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::size)>
void f3(T&&)
{}

int main()
{
    vector<int> coll;

    f1(coll); // ok
    f2(coll); // ok
    f3(coll); // ok
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9315a1354f89609a)

---

Generally, when using *Forwarding References*, [type modification utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_modifications) comes in very handy; primarily because *forwarding references* preserves both [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and [*`cv`* qualifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv).

Example 1:

- The code below [***fails***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17da6575fc53b616) to compile because `T` is deduced as `std::vector<int>&` and you cannot have a *non-const reference* bind to a temporary in `foo`:

  ```
  #include <vector>

  template<typename T>
  void foo(T&&){
      T nV = {3, 5, 6};
  }

  int main(){
      std::vector<int> Vec{1, 2 ,3, 4};
      foo(Vec);
  }
  ```
- You can remove the reference to get it to [***work***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3462f94e5ddbcf0c):

  ```
  #include <vector>

  template<typename T>
  void foo(T&&){
      using RemovedReferenceT = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
      RemovedReferenceT nV = {3, 5, 6};
  }

  int main(){
      std::vector<int> Vec{1, 2 ,3, 4};
      foo(Vec);
  }
  ```

Example 2 (builds upon example 1):

- Simply removing the reference would [***not work***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22b1a75db9c56b95) in the code below because the deduced type carries a `const` qualification, (aka, `T` is deduced as `const std::vector<int>&`) the new type, `RemoveReferenceT` is `const std::vector<int>`:

  ```
  #include <vector>

  template<typename T>
  void foo(T&&){
      using RemovedReferenceT = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
      RemovedReferenceT nV = {3, 5, 6};
      nV[2] = 7;                               //woopsie
  }

  int main(){
      const std::vector<int> Vec{1, 2 ,3, 4};  //note the const
      foo(Vec);
  }
  ```
- We [***can***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbea1491c3b04d7b) remove the `cv` qualifiers from the removed-reference's type.

  ```
  #include <vector>

  template<typename T>
  void foo(T&&){
      using RRT = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
      using Removed_CV_of_RRT = std::remove_cv_t<RRT>;

      Removed_CV_of_RRT nV = {3, 5, 6};
      nV[2] = 7;
  }

  int main(){
      const std::vector<int> Vec{1, 2 ,3, 4};
      foo(Vec);
  }
  ```

We can go on and on, of cause, we can [***combine***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc900b9aa08244ad) them in one line by nesting them, like: ==> `using D = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`.

Though there is [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) that is really powerful and [short](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d81a84f020e8a80) for such "combo kick" (but sometimes you want [a little less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732386/what-is-stddecay-and-when-it-should-be-used#comment40231735_25732639) of what `std::decay` does).