# Array Return fun movie_check()

Tags: c++, arrays, function, return

Now help me with this. Tell me where I am going wrong. I am making a simple movie-guessing game.

With `check_movie()` I am trying to update the movie from its temporary array after every guess.

I am getting the following error: incompatible types in assignment of `char*` to `char[100]`
Its something with the `check_movie()` Where am I going wrong?

I am trying to return an array from any function for the first time. I am just a beginner. I googled a lot about returning arrays but the examples were out of my brain's reach.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

void display_movie(char movie_temp[], int);
void display_life(int);
int win_player2(char movie_temp[]);
int check_life(char movie[], char, int);
char *check_movie(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char ch); //not sure about this func.

char *check_movie(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char ch)
{
    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]==ch)
        movie_temp[i]=movie[i];
    }

    return movie_temp;
}

void display_movie(char movie_temp[], int len)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
    cout<<movie_temp[i];
}

void display_life(int life)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<=life ; i++)
       cout<<"\3";
}


int check_life(char movie[], char ch, int life) 
{
    int count1=0;
    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]==ch)
           count1++;
    }
    if(count1==0)
       return --life;
    else
       return life;
}

int win_player2(char movie_temp[])
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0 ; movie_temp[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie_temp[i]=='_')
          count++;
    }
    if(count==0)
       return 0;
    else
       return 1;
}


int main()
{
    char movie[100], movie_temp[100], ch;
    cout<<"Enter the movie: ";
    cin.getline(movie,100);
    int len= strlen(movie);
    system("cls");


    for(int i=0 ; movie[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(movie[i]=='a' || movie[i]=='e' || movie[i]=='i' || movie[i]=='o' || 
           movie[i]=='u' || movie[i]==' ')
              movie_temp[i]= movie[i];
    else
        movie_temp[i]='_';
    }

    int life=9;
    cout<<"\nLives left: ";
    display_life(life);


    while(life!=0 || win_player2(movie_temp)!=0)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        display_movie(movie_temp, len);
        cout<<"\nEnter your guess: ";
        cin>>ch;
        life=check_life(movie, ch, life); //Here I update life
        //Updates life after every guess.

        movie_temp=check_movie(movie, movie_temp, ch);
        /*This part is getting me errors. I am trying to update movie_temp after every         
          guess.*/          


        cout<<"\n\nLives left: ";
        display_life(life);

   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are mixin C and C++. Why don't you define movies as `string` rather that as `char []` ?

Comment: `check_movie` should be `std::copy_if`. Also, `<iostream.h>` is, and never was, standard and `<conio.h>` is meant for DOS. `display_movie` would be a simple `std::cout << something` with a `std::string`. `display_life` uses an invalid escape character. `check_life` duplicates `std::count`, but would be better off just using `std::find`. Same with `win_player2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EDIT: Array return func movie\_check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752905/edit-array-return-func-movie-check)

Comment: @hivert : I want to have access of individual character of movie. So I thought `char[]` would be a good idea.

Comment: @lazygeek, If you have a `std::string s`, `s[i]` does the same thing.

Comment: @user1810087 : look at the comments bro. Everyone screwed my post. Now no one's interested in answering that even on my continuous edits.

Comment: <iostream.h> and <conio.h> Thats what we are taught at school. I just started learning C++ in this grade. I have no idea about `std::` thing. I would appreciate if you had help me sorting out this problem using concept of pointers.

Comment: @Everyone. Thanks for showing your concern. m24p solved my problem.

Comment: @lazygeek: Unfortunately, you're being taught a dialect of C++ that's been obsolete for a couple of decades. If you want to learn C++, drop the course and get yourself a [good modern book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242). If you don't, just drop the course.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thats my school bro. Can't do anything about it. I will join some good college in 2 years probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return anything from movie check.  Just update temp_array in the function.  Arrays are not passed by value.   See [Why can't we pass arrays to function by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454990/why-cant-we-pass-arrays-to-function-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

Look at your variable called **movie_temp**

```
char movie_temp[100]
// ...
movie_temp=check_movie(movie, movie_temp, ch);
```

Arrays can be thought of as *hardcoded memory addresses*.  So this would be analagous to the following code....

```
5 = this_function_returns_an_int();
```

Which is obviously wrong.  You can't assign to a constant.  If you want your memory address to be an assignable variable, you need a pointer, rather than an array.

If I might suggest, do something like this for check_movie.

```
// Updates movie_temp[] with characters from movie[] matching ch.  Wheel Of Fortune style.
// return true if any characters matched ch.  return false otherwise.
bool check_movie(char movie[], char movie_temp[], char ch);
```