# multiArray and multiArray[0] and &multiArray[0] same?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

On 6th line     instead of multiArray[0], when I write multiArray, program still works. Don't understand why. I was thinking before that multiArray is a pointer to multiArray[0] which is a pointer to multiArray[0][0]. So multiArray alone is a pointer to a pointer. multiArray[0] is a pointer to a 4 element int array. So it seems that multiArray and multiArray[0] must be different. But in below code, both work. Print function I wrote expects a pointer to a 4 element int array. So only multiArray[0] must work and multiArray must not work. But both works. Didn't understand that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArr(int(*ptr)[4]);

int i, k;

int main(void){

int multiArray[3][4] = { { 1, 5, 2, 4 }, { 0, 6, 3, 14 }, { 132, 4, 22, 5 } };

int(*point)[4] = multiArray[0];

for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{  
    printArr(point++);

}

getchar();

}

void printArr(int(*ptr)[4]){

int *temp = (int *)ptr;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", *temp);
    temp++;
}

puts("\n");
}
```

Comment: Can I Please know which Compiler you are Using.??? Because Your Code doesn't Compile on my machine(Using GCC).

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Express

Answer (score 4):

Someone else wrote "Multi-dimensional arrays are syntactic sugar for 1-D arrays".

This is sort of like saying that `int` is just syntactic sugar for a `unsigned char[4]` . You could do away with expressions like `4 + 5` and get the same result by manipulating arrays of 4 bytes.

You could even say that C is just syntactic sugar for a Universal Turing Machine script, if you want to take this concept a bit further.

The reality is that multi-dimensional arrays are a part of the type system in C, and they have syntax associated with them.  There's more than one way to skin a cat.

Moving on, the way C arranges what we are calling a multi-dimension array is to say:   "Arrays can only have one dimension, but the element type may itself be another array".  We say "multi-dimension array" as a matter of convenience, but the syntax and the type system actually reflect the one-dimensional nature of the array.

So, `int multiArray[3][4]` is an array of 3 elements. Each of those elements is an array of 4 `ints`.

In memory, an array's elements are stored contiguously -- regardless of what the element type is.  So, the memory layout is an array of 4 `int`, immediately followed by another array of 4 `int`, and finally another array of 4 `int`.

There are 12 contiguous `int` in memory, and in the C type system they are grouped up into 3 groups of 4.

You will note that the first `int` of the 12 is *also* the first `int` of the first group of 4. This is why we find that if we ask "What is the memory location of the first int?", "What is the memory location of the first group of 4 ints?", and "What is the memory location of the entire bloc of 12 ints?", we get the same answer every time. (In C, the memory location of a multi-byte object is considered to start at the location of its first byte).

Now, to talk about the pointer syntax and representation. In C, a pointer tells you where in memory an object can be found. There are two aspects to this: the memory location of the object, and what type of object it is.  (The size of the object is a corollary of the type).

Some presentations only focus on the first of those, they will say things like "A pointer is just a number".  But that is forgetting about the type information, which is a crucial part of a pointer.

When you print the pointer with `%p`, you lose the type information. You're just putting out the location in memory of the first byte. So they all look the same, despite the fact that the three pointers are pointing at differently-sized objects (which overlap each other like matruskha dolls).

In most implementations of C, the type information is all computed at compile-time, so if you try to understand C by comparing source code with assembly code (some people do this), you only see the memory-location part of the pointer. This can lead to misunderstanding if you forget that the type information is also crucial.

*Footnote:* All of this is independent of a couple of syntax quirks that C has; which have caused a lot of confusion over the years (but are also useful sometimes). The expression `x` is a shortcut for `&x[0]` if `x` is an array, except when used as the operand of `&` or `sizeof`. (Otherwise this would be a recursive definition!).  The second quirk is that if you write what looks like an array declarator in a function formal parameter list, it is actually as if you wrote a pointer declarator. I stress again that these are just syntax oddities, they are not saying anything fundamental about the nature of arrays and pointers, which is actually not that complicated.  The language would work just as well without both of these quirks.

Comment: You're right, the *syntactic sugar* of mine was too much. A good answer, hope it gets appropriate recognition. Could use some code though.

Comment: Why none of the books I have read mentions about the type property of pointers I don't understand.

Comment: I can Understand all your answers but OP's Code doesn't Compile on my GCC. It Says **initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]** So should i Assume that GCC is strict when Compiling.???????and this behavior can be compiler specific.??????

Comment: `int(*point)[4] = multiArray[0];` should be `&multiArray[0]` .

Answer (score 1):

Multidiemensional arrays `var_t arr[size_y][size_x]` provide means of declaring and accessing array elements (memory) in a conveniant manner. But all multidiemensional arrays are internally continuous memory blocks.

You may say that `arr[y][x] = arr[y*cols+x]`.

In terms of pointer-level, the pointers `multiArray` and `multiArray[0]` are the same, they're `int*` - though the formal *type* for arr will be `int (*)[2]`. Using that type will allow one to take advantage of all pointer mechanics (++ on such pointer will move the address by 8 bytes, not 4).

Try this:

```
void t1(int* param)
{
  printf("t1: %d\n", *param);
}

void t2(int** param)
{
  printf("t2: %d\n", **param);
}

int main(void) {
  int arr[2][2] = { { 1, 2 } , { 3, 4 } };
  t1(arr);    // works ok
  t1(arr[0]); // works ok
  t2(arr);    // seg fault
  t2(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: No. They are not all `int *`.

Comment: Then why **multiArray or *multiArray[0] must be written to access [0][0] the element? I mean why should I dereference multiArray 2 times and multiArray[0] only once if they point to same address? I don't get it.

Comment: multiArray is a pointer to multiArray[0]. Also multiArray[0] is itself a pointer (to multiArray[0][0]). Therefore, multiArray is a pointer to a pointer. Not all are int *.

Answer (score 0):

`int(*point)[4] = multiArray[0];`

This works because both `multiArray[0]` and `multiArray` point to same address, the address of first element of array: `multiArray[0][0]`.

However in this case, you may get a warning from compiler because type of `multiArray[0]` is `int*` while of `point` is `int [4]*`(pointer to array of `4` integers).

Comment: Am I correct in predicting that if he wants to not get warning in the above case he should do, `int(*point)[4] = &multiArray[0]`

Comment: Also, if I do multiArray instead of multiArray[0] , I do not get warning. what could be the reason for that.

Comment: omg &multiArray[0] works too. Eveything works in this program. :P

Comment: I think [Matt Ncabb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22984784/2628863) would have answered your query.