# No such thing as double decay in C?

Tags: c

I've been reading posts such as this one [Doesn't a 2D array decay to pointer to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987042/doesnt-a-2d-array-decay-to-pointer-to-pointer) as well as similar ones but I still don't see the big picture.

Take the following code as an example:

```
int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int *p;
p = *a; // This works even without derefrencing a
printf("%d\n", *p); // output is 1
```

`*a` gives a pointer to the first element of `a` which is an array of size 2 and it is assigned to `p`. Firstly, how does this not raise a warning? `p` is a pointer to an `int` and `*a` is an array.

We then print `*p` which outputs 1. How does this make sense without the array decaying twice? `*p` will be `{1,2}` so doesn't it make sense that `*p` decays into a pointer to the first element of the subarray?

But, in C this isn't possible. So what's going on?

Comment: `*a` is an array *of `int`.* So a pointer to it is of type `int *`.

Comment: When  you access an array, the variable is converted to a pointer to the first element. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) When you have a 2D array (actually an *array-of-arrays*), access causes the array `a`  to be converted to a pointer to the first 1D array that has type `int (*)[2]` (a *pointer-to-array* of `int[2]`). When you access the 1D array, by additional dereference, either `*a` or `a[0]` the type is `int[2]` -- which does what?? ... is converted to a pointer to the first `int` (element) of the first array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is, any time an expression with array type appears in a rvalue context, it "decays" into a pointer -- it is implicitly converted into a pointer to the array's 0th element.

So what does this mean for the expression `p = *a`?

Well, here `a` has array type (`int [2][2]`) so it is converted into a pointer (an `int (*)[2]`).  This pointer is then dereferenced (`*a`), which gives another array (an `int [2]`), so that also is converted into a pointer, this time an `int *`.

So there are two separate decay conversions in this statement (in some sense a "double decay"), but they are on two different array types and array values, even though the "bit pattern" of the resulting pointer is identical.

Comment: So, could I treat a[0] as an array name for the subarray?

Comment: Also, your explanation makes sense, but in the case that we assign p to a not *a, why would that raise a warning? It seems to me that both should work in the same way, right?

Comment: If you use `p = a;`, you get a warning because the pointer types do not match (`int *` vs `int (*)[2]`).   `a[0]` is just shorthand for `*(a + 0)` which is the same as `*a`.