# what does the name of an array in a 2d array point to?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array `a[2][2]`. Now it can be considered as consisting of two 1d arrays, `a[0]`and `a[1]`. Now as the name of an array points to the first element in an array, so `a[0]` is the address of `a[0][0]` i.e. `a[0] = &a[0][0]`. Also `a = &a[0]` according to the definition. So, combining the two `a = &(&a[0][0])`; but when I print a it gives the address of `a[0][0]` only i.e. `&a[0][0]`. Why is that?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22984784/2628863 The best I could find...

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiArray and multiArray\[0\] and &multiArray\[0\] same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983734/multiarray-and-multiarray0-and-multiarray0-same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the address of an address.

Address-of operator `&`, can be used only for variables. What is a variable? For example, `a` in `int a;` would be a variable, it would be a variable that holds an integer value. Or `b` in `int * b` would also be a variable, a variable that holds an address, to which the ones who have created all these languages decided to refer as *pointers*. Same thing for `c` in `int c[10];`, except that `c` there would be a constant variable, so you wouldn't be able to vary it; still, however, would be able to get the address of.

You can obtain the address of a variable because it is some data stored in some memory location for you. It has a definite place in memory; it does make sense to be able to know the address of a variable.

It doesn't make sense to know the address of an address. An address is just a number. Unlike a *pointer*, which -as I said- is *a variable that holds an address*, it doesn't have a definite place in memory for you to know of. It is just a number, so trying to take the address of an address as in `&(&a);`, makes just as much sense as trying to take the address of number 4 as in `&4` out of the blue.

As for the fact that each of `&a` and `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` from your example yielding the same result; it is true that all of those three variables start off from the same memory location. However, they are not identical, they have this important difference:

- `&a[0][0]` is the address of an integer.
- `&a[0]` is the address of an array of 2 integers.
- `&a` is the address of an array of 2 arrays of 2 integers.

So what they point at in the memory is different, like this:

```
// I'll use char so the bit-representation won't take long
char a[2][2] = {
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4 }
};

/*
&a is the address of this whole thing:
0000 0001   0000 0010   0000 0011   0000 0100   .... ....
^ &a here                                       ^ &a + 1 here

&a[0] is the address of this whole thing:
0000 0001   0000 0010   .... ....
^ &a[0] here            ^ &a[0] + 1 here

&a[0][0] is the address of just this:
0000 0001   .... ....
^ &a[0][0]  ^ &a[0][0] + 1
*/
```

So, what I'm trying to say is, they will differ when it comes to adding and subtracting numbers to and from them, and this is what they call as the *pointer arithmetic*.