# How are elements stored in a 2-D Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, multidimensional-array

If I declare an array say:

```
int arr[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
```

Now when I use the following command:

```
cout<<arr;
cout<<*arr;
```

Both of the above statements give me the address of 1. How does this work?

Should not *arr print elements 1,2,3 and 4?

Comment: _How are elements stored in a 2-D Array?_ AFAIK it's not specified how they are stored. It's an implementation detail and can differ between different compilers. Most compilers store the elements of  `int arr[3][4]` and `int arr[12]` in the same way but you shouldn't write code that depends on this detail.

Comment: Related, maybe even duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983734/multiarray-and-multiarray0-and-multiarray0-same/22984784#22984784

Did you try printing a 1D-array like this? It doesn't work either, you can't print arrays like that.