# C ++ pass by reference or pass by value?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So I thought that C++ works by value, except if you use pointers.

Although today I wrote this piece of code which works in a different manner than expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int A[],int arrSize);

bool binarySearch(int B[],int key,int arrSize2);

int main(){
    int numberArr[10] = {7,5,3,9,12,34,24,55,99,77};
    bool found;
    int key;


    bubbleSort(numberArr,10);
    /**
    uncomment this piece of code
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout<<numberArr[i]<<endl;       
    }

    **/


    cout<<"Give me the key: ";
    cin>>key;

    found=binarySearch(numberArr,key,10);

    cout<<found;
}

void bubbleSort(int A[],int arrSize){
    int temp;

        for(int i=0; i<arrSize-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<10; j++){
            if(A[i]>A[j]){
                temp=A[i];
                A[i]=A[j];
                A[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}



bool binarySearch(int B[],int key,int arrSize2){
    int i=0;
    bool found=false;

    while(i<arrSize2 && !found){
    if(B[i]==key)
    found=true;
    i++;
    }


    return found;
}
```

When running this it seems that the values in `numberArr` are changing (sorted) in the `main()` function as well, just uncomment the commented block.

Any thoughts on why are the values of `numberArr` changing in `main` function as well?

Comment: You are actually using pointers. `int B[]` is equivalent to `int *B` as parameter.

Comment: 1. @UlrichEckhardt It's not equivalent. 2. You probably want to be using `std::array`

Comment: It's two different ways to write the exact same thing, @Sahsahae, that pretty much counts as equivalent. Proof: Declare two functions with the same. If it was different, it would be an overload, thus two different functions. If the compiler considers them the same, you get an error about the redefinition though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int[]` as a type is essentially still a pointer due to [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). Therefore, you are passing an array "reference" (as in a value that will be used to "pass-by-reference", not as in an actual C++ reference like `int&`) and not a "value."

The "value" of `int[]` or `int*` itself is still "pass-by-value," it's just that the value is being used to access the "pointed-at" object memory by reference.

Comment: Pointer is a value like anything else.

Comment: I don't see what changed. Everything in C++ is, if we use outdated terminology, "pass-by-value" only. Ability to bind values as direct (and mutating) references instead of copying them into the function, doesn't change that fact either. You provide a value, and compiler does the rest for you. Providing an array, since it decays to a pointer, all that is copied, is the pointer. That's all there is to it.

Comment: That's why I put the term in "quotes," as the "idea" of pass-by-reference is "there," but in reality, everything is pass-by-value, as you said. Maybe it could be edited to be more clear on this...

Answer (score 2):

**In C++ you can't pass arrays by value.**
You are always passing a pointer to the first element. That is why you can switch from `foo(int a[])` to `foo(int * a)` without breaking the code.

*Example:* Some IDEs create main functions like this: `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` others as `int main(int argc, char ** argv)`.

You may take a look at [Why can't we pass arrays to function by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454990/why-cant-we-pass-arrays-to-function-by-value) This explains it very well.