# Get length of map array

Tags: c++

I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void shortestRemainingTime(map<string, string> processes[]){

    int size = (sizeof(processes)/sizeof(*processes));
    cout << size;

}

int main() {
    map<string, string> process { { "name", "open paint" }, { "remainingTime", "1000" } };
    map<string, string> process2{ { "name", "open photoshop" }, { "remainingTime", "500" } };
    map<string, string> process3{ { "name", "open word" }, { "remainingTime", "600" } };

    map<string, string> processes[] = {process, process2, process3};
    shortestRemainingTime(processes);
  return 0;
}
```

For now, I'm not making any calculation in `shortestRemainingTime` but, when I print the size of the array of the map `processes`, I'm getting 0, which isn't right.

How can I get the right length of this special array?

```
map<string, string> processes[] = {process, process2, process3};
```

Comment: Why not a proper struct for this data?

Comment: i'm begining with c++ :c

Comment: Great time to learn about creating a struct.

Comment: Hint: Use `std::vector` for arrays and `push_back`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, it [decays into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7454990/10871073) and, as such, you *cannot* use the `sizeof(processes)/sizeof(*processes)` paradigm/method on that.

You should be using a `std::vector` in place of your array, in which case you can then use its `size()` function. Here's a version of your code that does just that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::map;
using std::string;

// Note: Passing the vector by reference avoids having to copy a (potentially) 
// large object. Remove the "const" qualifier if you want the function to modify
// anything in the vector...
void shortestRemainingTime(const vector<map<string, string>> &processes)
{
    size_t size = processes.size();
    cout << size;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, string> process{ { "name", "open paint" }, { "remainingTime", "1000" } };
    map<string, string> process2{ { "name", "open photoshop" }, { "remainingTime", "500" } };
    map<string, string> process3{ { "name", "open word" }, { "remainingTime", "600" } };

    vector<map<string, string>> processes = { process, process2, process3 };
    shortestRemainingTime(processes);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, please see the following: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073) for good coding guidelines.

Comment: Here's that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454990/why-cant-we-pass-arrays-to-function-by-value

Comment: I was going to post the same. Not only are the sizeof results not what was expected, but also they are being obscured behind integer division. On my system, it produces 8 / 24 which is correctly 0 (as an integer)

Comment: Thank you, Adrian Mole, Kenny Ostrom and tadman, i'm going to apply your recomendations, this works well ;3

Comment: of course you should use std::vector, but you "can" use that array paradigm, just not inside the function. Arrays have to be passed along with their length as a function argument.